# Angular Catching events emitted by dynamically created objects

Tags: angular, event-handling, angular-dynamic-components

I have a component generator which is used to generate components on the fly and render them within its template. Any events emitted by a component needs to be caught by the component generator, data needs to be processed and processed data needs to be relayed to the next control.

I am working on Angular6 and although i have used the subscribe method in the code, the subscribed handler doesnt seem to be receiving the emitted event.

```
compRef.instance.selectedEntryEvent.subscribe(this.relaySelectionToNextComponent);
```

Following is the stackblitz link to the simple component generator code :-
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-componentgenerator

Let me know your thoughts.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the way to register the subscribe handler. All i had to do was:- `compRef.instance.selectedEntryEvent.subscribe(val => this.relaySelectionToNextComponent(val));`

Refer to the same stackblitz link :- 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-componentgenerator